# Is there a way to get notification when a transaction is ended in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger

I would like to get notification when my transaction (chaincode deploy or invoke) is ended. I use the REST API and I try to avoid the errors which say

```
'Error when querying chaincode: Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction for 97e1a9887ad9695f8ce5b0a8d0e6f250bb75ba19db49f2f610b4c450deba0233ee41d9d00a6c1142bfb021946ab36e506e454053ad5231414d43c9fba0a601c7 - ledger: resource not found)'.
```

Is there a way or should i just polling the transaction at the http://vp:5000/transactions/{txuuid} endpoint and post the query message after it gets back with proper result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to this is to have a block listener application that examines incoming blocks and parses them for criteria specified by your app.

[Example block listener](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/events/block-listener)

Comment: Just keep in mind that even if “Chaincode deploy” transaction is added to the block, it doesn’t mean that this new chaincode is ready for “query” requests immediately. It will take some time to run container with this chaincode.